# Constraint "email_order_to_sales_order" references table that does not exist

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade

When upgrading a site from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.0, the following error occurs during `setup:upgrade`

```
...
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_Amqp':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...Constraint "email_order_to_sales_order" references table that does not exist.
```

Comment: Do you install any third-party module? I think you should disable all of them and try run s:up once again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem occurs when running the setup:upgrade command while having the newer Dotdigitalgroup_Enterprise module enabled and the Dotdigitalgroup_Email module disabled.

Prior to this Enterprise module the Dotdigitalgroup_Email was not compatible with the split database setup that Magento2 Commerce offers, but this doesn't have to be the reason for disabling the Email module.

Comment: For me, it worked when I disable Dotdigitalgroup_Enterprise and run the setup upgrade. Then enable it and again run the setup upgrade

Comment: Hi Bas, nice to see you here! I've had the same problem but in my case it was because Elasticsearch somehow fell asleep. Simply restarting elasticsearch and running `set:up` again solved it for me.